# I create a script with php to convert xml to csv, but all results is vertical instead in one line with headers

Tags: php, xml, csv, simplexml

I want to create via php a script to convert xml to csv. I get the xml from url and with the follow code i make a csv. The problem is that the field goes vertical instead horizontal.

For example my xml is like:

```
<product>
   <id>1001</id>
   <sku>product1</sku>
   <name>Product 1 Name</name>
   <manufacturer>My Company</manufacturer>
</product>
<product>
   <id>1002</id>
   <sku>product2</sku>
   <name>Product 2 Name</name>
   <manufacturer>My Company</manufacturer>
</product>
<product>
   <id>1003</id>
   <sku>product3</sku>
   <name>Product 3 Name</name>
   <manufacturer>My Company</manufacturer>
</product>
```

And i get something like:

```
id,1001
sku,product1
name,"product 1"
manufacturer,My Company
id,1002
sku,product2
name,"product 2"
manufacturer,My Company
id,1003
sku,product3
name,"product 3"
manufacturer,My Company
```

instead this (this i want)

```
"id","sku","name","manufactuer"
"1001","product1","Product 1","My Company"
"1002","product2","Product 2","My Company"
"1003","product3","Product 3","My Company"
```

My code now is

```
file_put_contents("products.xml", fopen("https://xml.mysite.com/get.asp?xml=products&key=myxml", 'r'));

    if (file_exists('products.xml')){
       $xml = simplexml_load_file('products.xml');
       file_put_contents("products.csv", "");
       $f = fopen('products.csv', 'w');
       createCsv($xml, $f);
       fclose($f);
    }

    function createCsv($xml,$f){
        foreach ($xml->children() as $item) {
           $hasChild = (count($item->children()) > 0)?true:false;
            if(!$hasChild){
                $put_arr = array($item->getName(),$item); 
                fputcsv($f, $put_arr ,',','"');
            } else {
                createCsv($item, $f);
            }
        }
    }
```

What i can do please?

Comment: See the first [comment here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php#102277) for a really simple way to convert XML to an array that works as long as your XML is relatively simple

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML (and DOM) can use Xpath to fetch elements from an XML. You would need one expression for the rows and a list of expressions for the columns.

```php
function readRowsFromSimpleXML(
  SimpleXMLElement $element, string $rowExpression, array $columnExpressions
): Generator {
    foreach ($element->xpath($rowExpression) as $rowNode) {
        $row = [];
        foreach ($columnExpressions as $column => $expression) {
            $row[$column] = (string)($rowNode->xpath($expression)[0] ?? '');
        }
        yield $row;
    }
}

$rows = readRowsFromSimpleXML(
  simplexml_load_file('products.xml'), 
  '//product',
  $columns = [
      'id' => './id',
      'sku' => './sku',
      'name' => './name',
      'price' => './price',
      'manufacturer' => './manufacturer'
  ]
);
```

`readRowsFromSimpleXML(...)` will return a `Generator`. It will not read the data yet. This will only happen if you resolve it - for example with `foreach()`.

Addressing the row and column data explicitly keeps the output more stable. It even work if an element is missing. I added a `price` column to show this.

To put this into a CSV you have to iterate the generator:

```php
$fh = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fputcsv($fh, array_keys($columns));
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fh, array_values($row));
}
```

Output:

```
id,sku,name,price,manufacturer
1001,product1,"Product 1 Name",,"My Company"
1002,product2,"Product 2 Name",,"My Company"
1003,product3,"Product 3 Name",,"My Company"
```

This works with more complex expressions as well. For example reading a currency attribute of the price element or multiple images:

```php
$columns = [
    'id' => './id',
    'sku' => './sku',
    'name' => './name',
    'manufacturer' => './manufacturer',
    'price' => './price',
    'price' => './price/@currency',
    'image0' => '(./image)[1]',
    'image1' => '(./image)[2]'
]';
```

If you need to aggregate values, add a callback to the column definition.

```
function readRowsFromSimpleXML(
  SimpleXMLElement $element, string $rowExpression, array $columnExpressions
): Generator {
    foreach ($element->xpath($rowExpression) as $rowNode) {
        $row = [];
        foreach ($columnExpressions as $column => $options) {
            if (is_array($options)) {
                [$expression, $callback] = $options;
            } else {
                $expression = $options;
                $callback = null;
            }
            $values = $rowNode->xpath($expression);
            if ($callback) {
                $row[$column] = $callback($values);
            } else {
                $row[$column] = (string)($rowNode->xpath($expression)[0] ?? '');
            }
        }
        yield $row;
    }
}

$rows = readRowsFromSimpleXML(
  simplexml_load_file('products.xml'), 
  '//product',
  $columns = [
      'id' => './id',
      'sku' => './sku',
      // ...
      'categories' => [ './category', fn ($values) => implode(',', $values) ]
  ]
);
```

Complex configuration arrays are difficult to maintain. A more encapsulated approach would be a class. The following class works with SimpleXML and DOM. The fields/columns are added with a method.

```php
class XMLRecordsReader implements \IteratorAggregate {
    
    private $_source;
    private $_expression = './*';
    private $_fields = [];
    
    public function __construct($source) {
        if ($source instanceof \SimpleXMLElement) {
            $this->_source = dom_import_simplexml($source);
            return;
        } 
        if ($source instanceof \DOMNode) {
            $this->_source = $source;
            return;
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Need SimpleXMLElement or DOMNode $source.');
    }
    
    public function setExpression(string $expression): self {
        $this->_expression = $expression;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function addField(string $name, string $expression, callable $mapper = null): self {
        $this->_fields[$name] = [$expression, $mapper];
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getIterator(): \Generator {
        $xpath = new DOMXpath(
            $this->_source instanceof DOMDocument ? $this->_source : $this->_source->ownerDocument
        );
        foreach ($xpath->evaluate($this->_expression, $this->_source) as $node) {
            $record = [];
            foreach ($this->_fields as $field => $options) {
                [$expression, $mapper] = $options;
                $values = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $node);
                if ($mapper) {
                    $record[$field] = $mapper($values);
                } else if ($values instanceof DOMNodeList) {
                    $value = $values[0] ?? null;
                    $record[$field] = $value->textContent ?? '';
                } else {
                    $record[$field] = (string)($values ?? '');
                }
            }
            yield $record;
        }
    }
}

$reader = new XMLRecordsReader(
  simplexml_load_file('products.xml'), 
);
$reader
  ->addField('id', './id')
  ->addField('sku', './sku')
  ->addField('name', './name')
  ->addField('manufacturer', './manufacturer')
  ->addField('price', './price')
  ->addField('currency', './price/@currency')
  ->addField('image0', '(./image)[1]')
  ->addField('image1', '(./image)[2]')
  ->addField(
      'categories', 
      './category', 
      fn (\DOMNodeList $values) => implode(
          ',', 
          array_map(
              fn (\DOMNode $node) => $node->textContent,
              iterator_to_array($values)
          )
      )
  );

var_dump(iterator_to_array($reader));
```

Comment: Thank you. Is any way to get automatically the field names? Because now for example i write 5 columns. In real project i have over 50 and not static. (in one xml maybe i have 45, in other 60, in other 30)

Comment: Of course you could read the tag names from the XML and build the expression from them, but I would recommend using a fixed definition. Think about it, the XML could change and this would directly pass trough to your export - making it unstable. You can't even document the export because you do not control it.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. One last question. In one xml tag <gallery></gallery> The structure inside is <image>Url 1st photo</image> <image>Url 2st photo</image> <image>Url 3rd photo</image>Etc…. Is any way in your above code to create in csv dynamic fields with name ‘image0’ => 1st url, ‘image1’ => 2nd url etc? Thanks

Comment: Sure, I added an example for more complex expressions.